Limit problem involving hyperbolic functions.
Given that $\tanh \left(\dfrac{\sqrt{T^2(a^2-1)+1}}{a^2\sqrt{1-T^2}}\right)=\dfrac{\sqrt{1-T^2}}{\sqrt{T^2(a^2-1)+1}}$. Here $T$ is a function of $a$. I'm trying to prove that $$\lim_{a \to \infty} T = \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}.$$ Numerical Evidences showed that this is true. Any hint would help.

Double check what you've written down (especially the repeating $T$ inside the $\tanh$) because I compute a different limit which is around $~0.65$

@NinadMunshi I checked and removed the repeated T. What method did you use?

The limit is the unique positive real root of the equation $T^4  = (1 - T^2 )^3$. It can be expressed using radicals and its numerical value is $t = 0.65586561\ldots$.

You all correct. I missed a square root on right hand side. That gives the exact answer.

One of my old professors used to say (I quote him) :  "We shall always be closer to $0$ than to $\infty$".
So, let $a=\frac 1 b$.
$$\text{rhs}=\frac{ b(1-T^2)} {\sqrt{ T^2+b^2 \left(1-T^2\right)}}$$
$$\text{lhs}=\tanh\left(\frac{b\sqrt{ T^2+b^2 \left(1-T^2\right)} } {\sqrt{1-T^2} }   \right)$$
Compose Taylor series from inside to outside to obtain
$$\text{lhs - rhs}=
   \left(\frac{T^2-1}{\sqrt{T^2}}+\frac{\sqrt{T^2}}{\sqrt{1-T^2}}
   \right)b+O\left(b^3\right)$$ So, squaring, the leading term is
$$\frac{T^6-2 T^4+3 T^2-1}{T^2 \left(T^2-1\right)}$$ which is a cubic in $T^2$. Its solution is
$$T^2=\frac{2}{3} \left(1-\sqrt{5} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{11}{10 \sqrt{5}}\right)\right)\right)$$ which is the square of the number already given by @Ninad Munshi and @Gary.

We know that
\begin{equation*}
\tanh z\ =\ \dfrac{z}{1+\dfrac{z^{2}}{3+\dfrac{z^{2}}{5+\dfrac{z^{2}}{7+\dfrac{z^{2}}{\vdots }}}}}
\end{equation*}
Let $\displaystyle z=\dfrac{\sqrt{T^{2}\left( a^{2} -1\right) +T}}{a^{2}\sqrt{1-T^{2}}} .$ We can see that when $\displaystyle \ a\ \rightarrow \infty $, $\displaystyle z^{2}\rightarrow 0$ rapidely.
Therefore, we can assume that $\displaystyle \tanh z\ \approx \ z$.
\begin{align*}
\tanh\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{T^{2}\left( a^{2} -1\right) +1}}{a^{2}\sqrt{1-T^{2}}}\right) & =\dfrac{\sqrt{1-T^{2}}}{\sqrt{T^{2}\left( a^{2} -1\right) +1}}\\
\Longrightarrow \dfrac{\sqrt{T^{2}\left( a^{2} -1\right) +1}}{a^{2}\sqrt{1-T^{2}}} & =\dfrac{\sqrt{1-T^{2}}}{\sqrt{T^{2}\left( a^{2} -1\right) +1}}\\
T^{2} & =\dfrac{a^{2} -1}{2a^{2} -1}\\
\lim _{a\rightarrow \infty } T & =\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\end{align*}
